# How to give grant select on full database to user in DB2 z/OS

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I want to grant select rights on all the tables in database to particular user in db2 z/OS or mainframe.
I know with following query, we can grant select on table to user by running with ibmuser.

```
GRANT SELECT ON <TableName> TO <UserName>
```

However I have tried the same by using Db2 z/OS stored procedure in ibmuser:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GRANT_SELECT_ON_DB(
IN DatabaseName   varchar(255),
IN UserName    varchar(255))
   LANGUAGE SQL
   BEGIN
      DECLARE v_NAME VARCHAR(64);
      DECLARE v_CREATOR VARCHAR(64);
      DECLARE v_GrantQuery VARCHAR(320);
      DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
      (SELECT NAME,CREATOR FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES tabs WHERE  upper(dBname)=upper(DatabaseName));
      OPEN c1;
      fetch_loop:
      LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO v_NAME,v_CREATOR ;
       SET v_GrantQuery = 'grant select on '|| v_CREATOR ||'.'|| v_NAME ||' to  '|| UserName;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_GrantQuery;
      END LOOP fetch_loop;
      CLOSE c1;
END%
```

On calling of stored procedure, it get stuck in loading and not producing any results or error.
`call IBMUSER.GRANT_SELECT_ON_DB('<DatabaseName>','<UserName>')%`

Also `GRANT SELECT ON <DatabaseName> TO <UserName>` is not working as it is not supported in DB2 z/OS.
Please suggest. May be I am missing some basics.

Comment: Yes, you are missing some basics. Speak with your Z/OS-DBA . For Db2-on-Z, most sites have quite specific change management requirements.

Comment: Read about condition handlers in SQL PL. You need to exit the loop on a NOT FOUND condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below procedure, it worked for me:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GRANT_SELECT_ON_DB(IN DatabaseName   varchar(255),
    IN UserName    varchar(255))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v_NAME VARCHAR(400);
        DECLARE v_CREATOR VARCHAR(400);
        DECLARE v_GrantQuery VARCHAR(1000);
        FOR v1 AS
        c1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT NAME,CREATOR FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES tabs WHERE  upper(dBname)=upper(DatabaseName)
        DO
            SET v_NAME = NAME;
            SET v_CREATOR = CREATOR;
            SET v_GrantQuery = 'grant select on '|| v_CREATOR ||'.'|| v_NAME ||' to  '|| UserName;
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_GrantQuery;
        END FOR;
    END%
    
    call IBMUSER.GRANT_SELECT_ON_DB('<DatabaseName>','<UserName>')%
```